# Change form submission (enter to tab)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a real basic form (code below) with a bunch of back-panel PhP. There is a scanner being used to input the data, but instead of tab after each item, it sends an "enter" command.

Is it viable to add javascript to cause enter to instead tab to the next form field, and upon the last form field, submit it instead? I have found a few scripts online, but none that I have tried have worked in Firefox/Chrome.

CODE:

```
<html><head><title>Barcode Generation</title></head><body>
<fieldset style="width: 300px;">
<form action="generator.php" method="post">
Invoice Number:<input type="text" name="invoice" /><br />
Model Number:<input type="text" name="model" /><br />
Serial Number:<input type="text" name="serial" /><br />
<input type="hidden" name="reload" value="true" />
<input type="submit" />
</form><br /><a href=null>en espanol</a></fieldset>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

<strike>You'll need to implement an 'onsubmit' handler for the form which checks that the [ENTER] key was pressed from the "correct" field (or the form is adequately filled). If not, the handler should just return false (to prevent submission).</strike> (Only need to do the next bit.)

Then you'll need to implement an 'onkeypress' handler for each input that can be scanned, and when you get an [ENTER] key, <strike>call .preventDefault()</strike> prevent submission of the form, and <strike>trigger a [TAB] 'keypress' event</strike>  .focus() the next field.

**Update:** this works for me:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Barcode Generation</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

      function validate() {
        return ((/\S+/.test($('input[name="invoice"]').val())) &&
                (/\S+/.test($('input[name="model"]').val())) &&
                (/\S+/.test($('input[name="serial"]').val())));
      }

      $().ready(function(){
        $('#generator_form')
          .submit(validate)
          .find('input[type="text"]')
            .keypress(function(evt) {
              if (evt.which == 13) { // ENTER pressed
                var next_elem;
                if (evt.target.name == 'invoice') { next_elem = $('input[name="model"]'); }
                else if (evt.target.name == 'model') { next_elem = $('input[name="serial"]'); }
                else if (evt.target.name == 'serial') { return validate(); }
                $(next_elem).focus();
                return false;
              } else { // some other key pressed
                return true;
              }
            })
          .end();
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <fieldset style="width: 300px;">
      <form id="generator_form" action="generator.php" method="post">
        Invoice Number:<input type="text" name="invoice" /><br />
        Model Number:<input type="text" name="model" /><br />
        Serial Number:<input type="text" name="serial" /><br />
        <input type="hidden" name="reload" value="true" />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <br />
      <a href=null>en espanol</a>
    </fieldset>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Updated:** to submit on [ENTER] in 'serial' field.

**Updated:** to properly validate in all cases.

Comment: any advice for resources to learn that? I know absolutely 0 javascript at all :(

Comment: the jQuery documentation for Events deals with these topics nicely and provides examples: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/

Comment: If you can wait a little while, I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I'd rather catch the enter key on the input fields and then use `e.stopPropagation()` to prevent it from bubbling up to the form.

Comment: Yes, that's equivalent to the "return false" part, but doesn't focus the next field (at least in my testing - FF11.0 Linux/AMD64).

Comment: thanks David, I was actually getting really close to something similar on my own by poking and prodding stuff until it was maybe working. Only problem I see is that when pressing enter on the 3rd field it would need to submit, rather than tab to submit. I should be able to get that figured out how to do it though. Thanks again!

Comment: Updated! It now submits from the 'serial' field.

Comment: awesome, thanks a ton - I can go on vacation now with peace of mind that this thing is done! on a side note (this is actually preferred for my implementation) you validate the form, but if the the user presses enter on the 3rd field, it submits regardless of validation.

Comment: Interesting, so I guess you need to manually call the validation function in that case, before allowing the default action. I've updated it to handle that case.